# HTML Table Footer (`tfoot`) Cell (`td`) Not Taking Full Width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a React project where I have a table with a footer (`tfoot`). In the footer, I have a single row (`tr`) with a single cell (`td`) that is supposed to span across all columns of the table. I've set the `colSpan` attribute to 5 (as there are 5 columns in my table), and I'm trying to make this `td` take up all the space in the row.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { User } from '../core/models/User.tsx'
import teamsIcon from '../assets/teams.svg'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import moreIcon from '../assets/more-horizontal.svg'
import { FetchUserRepository } from '../infra/repositories/FetchUserRepository.tsx'
import leftArrowIcon from '../assets/arrow-left.svg'
import rightArrowIcon from '../assets/arrow-right.svg'

const userRepository = new FetchUserRepository()

export function UserAccessTable() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
  const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(0)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    userRepository
      .getUsersPage(1, 15)
      .then(({ users, totalPage }) => {
        setUsers(users)
        setTotalPage(totalPage)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error))
  }, [])

  return (
    <StyledUserAccessTable>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Teams</th>
            <th>Access</th>
            <th>Last Login</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
              <td>
                <img src={user.avatar} alt="User Avatar" />
                <div>
                  <span>{user.name}</span>
                  <span>{user.email}</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span>
                  <img src={teamsIcon} alt={user.groups[0]} />
                  {user.groups[0]}
                </span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span>On {user.access.length} products</span>
              </td>
              <td>{format(new Date(user.last_login), 'dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm')}</td>
              <td>
                <img src={moreIcon} alt={'more'} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={5} className={'pagination'}>
              <span>
                <img src={leftArrowIcon} alt={'Previous Page'} />
              </span>
              {Array.from({ length: totalPage }, (_, index) => index + 1).map(
                (page) => (
                  <span key={page}>{page}</span>
                ),
              )}
              <span>
                <img src={rightArrowIcon} alt={'Next Page'} />
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </StyledUserAccessTable>
  )
}

const StyledUserAccessTable = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid var(--border-primary);
  border-radius: var(--radius-md);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 32px;

  table {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-primary);
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: var(--radius-md);
    overflow: hidden;

    thead {
      border: 0;
      color: var(--text-secondary);
      background-color: var(--surface-secondary);

      th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }
    }

    tr {
      border: solid 1px var(--border-primary);

      td {
        padding: 15px 20px;

        div {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;

          span:first-child {
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 13px;
            line-height: 19px;
            color: var(--text-primary);
          }

          span {
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: var(--text-third);
          }
        }
      }

      td:first-child {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;

        img {
          border-radius: 50%;
          width: 32px;
          height: 32px;
          object-fit: cover;
          margin-right: 20px;
        }
      }

      td:nth-child(2) {
        span {
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;

          gap: 4px;
          border: 1px solid var(--border-primary);
          border-radius: 100px;

          padding: 3px 8px;
          font-size: 11px;
          line-height: 16px;
        }
      }

      td:nth-child(3) {
        span {
          font-size: 12px;
          line-height: 18px;
          color: var(--text-secondary);
          border-bottom: 1px dashed #66708580;
        }
      }

      td:nth-child(4) {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: var(--text-third);
      }
    }

    tfoot {
      tr {
        border: purple solid 10px;
        width: 100%;

        td {
          border: 1px red solid;

          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;

          width: 100%;
          padding: 16px 20px;

          img {
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
          }

          span {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid var(--border-primary);
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 16px;
            color: var(--text-secondary);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Despite setting `colSpan` to 5 and `width` to 100%, the `td` is only taking up the left half of the table. I've tried removing the `flex-grow: 1;` rule and adding `width: 100%;` to the CSS rules for the `td` element, but it didn't solve the issue.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: For colspan to work, the td must be `display:table-cell`, not `display:flex`

Comment: Oh I see. Then I am forced to add a div wrapping the span to use the flexDirection row

It worked though. Thank you!

Comment: any specific reason you are not using grid (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)?